# Automatic fill colour but opposite to theme in diagrams.net aka draw.io

Tags: draw.io, diagrams.net

In diagrams.net aka draw.io how can a shape have a fill colour that is

- black if the diagram is viewed with light appearance.
- white if the diagram is viewed with dark appearance.

A shape can have the line colour like that, by opening the Edit Style dialog and setting strokeColor=default in the key-value pairs.

[image: Edit Style dialog with strokeColor=default; highlighted.]

If fillColor=default is set then the fill colour will be

- white if the diagram is viewed with light appearance.
- black if the diagram is viewed with dark appearance.

That's the opposite to what I want for some shapes.

Context is that I'm drawing UML activity diagrams. The start node should be a black circle, in light appearance, or a white circle, in dark appearance.

Maybe there's another special value to which fillColor can be set? I couldn't find documentation of the possible values.

Cheers, Jim

Answer (score 1):

Just a note to say that the good people at https://groups.google.com/g/drawio provided an answer.

```
fillColor=strokeColor
```

[image]

Cheers, Jim